# Android activity Restarts When orientation changes

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation

My app seems to restart when it detects an orientation change. Well not really.

I only have portrait orientation enabled though.

In log cat I can see that my app is still doing calculations, but my progress dialog disappears.

What is going on?

In my manifest file this is my activity.

```
<activity
            android:name=".xxxActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason why you're listening for the orientation change with android:configChanges="orientation"?

If not, remove that and I suspect your problem will go away.

add this right after the super call

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Comment: Hi, I removed the config changes. The problems are still there.

Comment: can you provide a bit more detail about what specifically the problem "is", please? Have you put in some logging into the onCreate method to see if your app is actually calling it when it rotates?

Comment: I added a log in onCreate. It is being called when I rotate.

Comment: right... that's what it should be doing... so what would you *like to see happen? Are you looking to lock your orientation and have it not call onCreate when you rotate the device?

Comment: Right, I do not want it to call onCreate. I would like my application to continue like nothing happened.

Comment: look at my edit... Note, however, that it will no longer react to being rotated at all.  If my answer helps you, don't forget to gimme the green checkmark! (and welcome to stack!) :)

Comment: @Mich: Like Genia said, post some Java codes, mate, so we can help you. Without your codes, I guess you haven't set this `android:screenOrientation="nosensor"` and/or you haven't set the method `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` suggested by Genia correctly. Either one would have caused your activity to restart as per Android normal activity lifecycle. Also, if you're targeting Android 3.2 or higher, don't forget to do this `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"`

Answer (score 0):

Better to change configChanges to

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

I guess, that activity is restarted, because you forgot to add `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration)` method in your activity.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration)
It can be empty but shold be in the activity.

Also `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` is not needed.